# SUPEE 7405 for Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, security, patches, supee-7405

Didn't Magento release SUPEE 7405 Patch for Magento 2.0 and What about the Enterprise edition?

Answer (score 5):

As it was already mentioned here: SUPEE-7504 is a patch bundle for Magento 1.X.

Next to this, also the Magento **Community Edition 1.9.2.3** and **Enterprise Edition 1.14.2.3** were released, as well as the **Community and Enterprise Edition 2.0.1**.

Some of the issues that were fixed for 1.X got also fixed for 2.X:

- Guest order view protection code vulnerable to brute-force attack -
  APPSEC-1270
- XSS in Product Custom Options - APPSEC-1267
- Injected code can be stored in database - APPSEC-1240

Answer (score 2):

SUPEE-7405 is a Magento 1.X patch only. It is relevant for both CE and EE editions.

Regarding Magento 2.X, the new version 2.0.1 has been released and can be found here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Answer (score 0):

SUPEE-7405 is a bundle of patches for Magento 1.x that resolve several security-related issues.

Magento 2.0.1 has been released and is not affected

Answer (score 0):

I have the 1.x CE and EE patches here

https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/tree/master/current-patches

I just checked Magento EE support and there are no "Patches" yet 2.x